# Cypress return value in class method

Tags: javascript, cypress, pageobjects

I am trying to apply the Page Object Model (POM) to some tests using Cypress.

Unfortunaly I can't read some webelement value and return it as a method or function value. I needed to make something like these to work:

```
var1 = cy.get("input#inpUserName").then(($var1) => {
    cy.log($var1.val());
})

cy.log(var1)
```

But all I could do was:

```
cy.get("input#inpUserName").then(($var1) => {
    cy.log($var1.val());
})
```

For what I researched I think there is no solution for that with Cypress. But I'd like to see if anyone has any suggestion about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a value from a POM method, but it is Promise-like so you use `.then()` to access the value.

```js
class Login {
  ...
  username() {
    return cy.get("input#inpUserName").then(($var1) => {
      return $var1.val()
    })
  }
}

...

const login = new Login()

login.username().then(username => {
  expect(username).to.eq('Joe')
})
```